# Display date with sum of weeks in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

1- I have a number of weeks from an input field:

```js
$("#numberWeek").on("keyup", function(){
  var numberWeek =  $(this).val();
  console.log(numberWeek);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="numberWeek" />
```

2- I have the  number of the current week:

```js
var todayDate = new Date();
var currentWeek = (0 | todayDate.getDate() / 7) + 1;
console.log(currentWeek);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

3- How can I display the **date** that we will find when we start to count **from** the current week (**currentWeek**)  **to** the number of weeks that is in the variable **numberWeek**  in this format : 26/07/2018 ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I'm still trying but it's still hard for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the moment.js ([here](https://momentjs.com/) documentation) library to achieve this easily, just use `add` method and pass as parameter week, something like this:

```
moment(todayDate).add(numberWeek, 'weeks').calendar()
```

here the idea working: https://jsbin.com/rokiluxosi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Diasline you're welcome